# asp-for tag helper showing 'CS1061' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am new to the ASP.NET core MVC framework. I am trying to implement server-side validation on the form using tag helper in my MVC application.
When I am trying to use asp-for tag helper, it is showing [CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)) error for the string that I am passing as a value of the tag helper.

Below is the code.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
<body>
  <form class="signup" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" asp-action="CreateUser" method="POST">
       <div class="form-div">
           <div class="name-section">
              <input class="textfields field-margin" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="firstname" asp-for="firstname">  // getting error here.
              <input class="textfields" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lastname">   
       </div>
   </form>
<body>
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong here. Please let me know if additional details are required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using asp-for , you need to add model to your view in order you could assign the model property.

```
@model MyViewModel
```

or if you have the one already , check spelling